# Add an item to a list in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase database structure. `uIds` is a type of `List<String>`. I am trying to add another uId under `uIds` with an incremented index. `setValue()` and `updateChildren()` would require me to retrieve existing data, and `push()` will add an item with a randomly generated string as a key instead of an incremented index. Is there a simpler way that does not require to retrieve the existing data? Thanks!

```
  "requests" : {
    "request001" : {
      "interests" : [ "x" ],
      "live" : true,
      "uIds" : [ "user1" ]  // <---- from this
    },
    "request002" : {
      "interests" : [ "y" ],
      "live" : true,
      "uIds" : [ "user2" ]
    }
  }
```

### --------------------------------

Edit:

Sorry for the unclarity. Let me elaborate to make it clear.
Say I have the above database and want to update it to the following.

```
  "requests" : {
    "-KSVYZwUQPfyosiyRVdr" : {
      "interests" : [ "x" ],
      "live" : true,
      "uIds" : [ "user1", "user2" ]   // <--- to this
    },
    "-KSl1L60g0tW5voyv0VU" : {
      "interests" : [ "y" ],
      "live" : true,
      "uIds" : [ "user2" ]
    }
  }
```

ishmaelMakitla's suggestion, `mDatabase.child("requests").child("request001").setValue(newRequest)`, will overwrite the "request001" with "newRequest". So I should retrieve the existing data of "request001" and add "user2" to the list `uIds`. It will be something like this:

```
mDatabase.child("requests").child("request001").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Request newRequest = dataSnapshot.getValue(Request.class);
        newRequest.uIds.add("user2");
        mDatabase.child("requests").child("request001").setValue(newRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

});
```

But I am wondering if this process is necessary since what I am trying to do is simply to add one item to the list `uIds`.

Comment: What do you mean my retrieve data ? It's all about updating. Please try to clear that point a little more so it's easier to help you.

Comment: By retrieving data, I mean running a ValueEventListener to read the existing  list of uIds

Comment: But you don't have to attach listeners to update children. You just need a reference. Only when you specifically want to read data you would use listeners.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [Firebase documentation on creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) proposes that you use a different data structure:

```
"requests" : {
  "-KSVYZwUQPfyosiyRVdr" : {
    "interests" : { "x": true },
    "live" : true,
    "uIds" : { 
      "user1": true, 
      "user2": true 
    }
  },
  "-KSl1L60g0tW5voyv0VU" : {
    "interests" : { "y": true },
    "live" : true,
    "uIds" : { 
      "user2": true 
    }
  }
}
```

Here are a few of the reasons why this data structure works better:

- each uid can now automatically only appear once. We've essentially modeled our data as a *set*, instead of using an array.
- adding an item is now as easy as `ref.child("uUids").child("user3").setValue(true)`
- you can now check if a uid exists in your security rules.

I have started re-iterating to myself: *whenever you find yourself doing `array.contains("xyz")`, you should probably be using a set instead of an array.* The above mapping with `"key": true` is an implementation of a set on Firebase.

## Efficiency

Some people may think arrays are a more efficient way of storing the data, but in the case of Firebase that is not true:

What you see:

```
"uIds" : [ "user1", "user2" ]
```

What Firebase stores:

```
"uIds" : {
  "0": "user1",
  "1": "user2"
}
```

So storing a set is pretty much the same:

```
"uIds" : { 
  "user1": true, 
  "user2": true 
}
```

Comment: And if it was web javascript it would be ref.child("uUids").child("user3").set(true);

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean when you say setValue, etc require you to retrieve existing data. The basic flow for inserting new record is as follows:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// get reference to your Firebase Database.
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
//and here you add a new child to your 'requests' collection
//I am assuming you have a Request model like this..
Request newRequest = new Request(some-params);
mDatabase.child("requests").child(someRequestId).setValue(newRequest);
```

You can take a look at basic usage guide for [Saving Data on Android Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data).

**Update:**
Following your comment - I think what you are looking to do can be achieved like this:
You use the `push()` method which generates a unique ID every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference:

```
Firebase newRequestRef = mDatabase.child("request").push();
newRequestRef.setValue(newRequest);
```

This should do it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's right! This is exactly what confused me in his question.

Comment: @Han, it seems you just want to generate the ID first before inserting the request - in that case, you simply use the `push` which will return a `Ref`, and then use this `Ref` to `setValue` to the new request. I have added this in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good old article from the Firebase official blog explaining why we should avoid array in our database : [Arrays are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

So it's not possible to modify an array without replacing the array. I suggest to change your database structure to this

```
"requests" : {
    "<pushKey1>" : {
        "interests" : [ "x" ],
        "live" : true,
        "uIds" : {
            "<pushKey1>" : "user1",
            "<pushKey2>" : "user2"
        }
    },
    "<pushKey2>" : {
        "interests" : [ "y" ],
        "live" : true,
        "uIds" : {
            "<pushKey1>" : "user2"
        }
    }
}
```

To get the `pushKey`, you can use [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) method (the same as what you have done to each `Request` item)

Then the code will be like this if you just want to add a new uid to a request.

```
String requestKey = "request001";
mDatabase.child("requests").child(requestKey).child("uIds").push().setValue("user2");
```

Comment here if you have questions, hope this helps :)

Comment: I am a little confused. As we are not prefering arrays then why are there arrays against "interests" ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding 2 cents to Frank van Puffelen answer, you can use the key from push operation as a unique identifier of your request. Plus if you use hash map to update child then your DB will not be overridden

```
 // Create a node on Server and get key
  String requestID = AdminController.getInstance().referenceFromUrl
                        .child(END_POINT_REQUESTS)
                        .push().getKey();

  //use key as ID for your Object which you want to push as unique identifier of your model
  requestToPush.setRequestId(requestID );

 //Add updated Model Object in a Map to update DB instead of over writing
 requestsMap.put(requestID , requestToPush);

 //Update newly created DB nodes with data
   referenceFromUrl
            .child(END_POINT_REQUESTS)
            .updateChildren(productsMap,
                    new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if (databaseError != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error: Data could not be saved "
                                        + databaseError.getMessage());
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Success : Data saved successfully.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

**Result**

[image]