# How to update firebase with array of objects?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For an example we have the database:

```
//the database
firebase: {
  1: a,
  2: b,
  3: c
}

//the ref 
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

//what we need
var change = [
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "y"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "z"
  },
];

//a possible way how we want
firebaseRef.update({
  change[0].id: change[0].value,
  change[1].id: change[1].value
})
```

I have a few questions.

The last block needs to loop through the array. But i don't know if it is a good practice to call update repeatedly.

The second important thing is that while the keys above only have one value, it's good, but if it's an object which has a few properties, the only one we want to set will override the other properties. I think the best way to solve this to create a loop with setting the database's child to the array's actual object's id or key, and then update the necessary properties.

But isn't it a bad practice to loop through an array and call the update function repeatedly?

Comment: I don't see any looping in the code you posted. What exactly is your question/problem. Also note that asking for best/bad practice can be seen as off-topic because it asks for opinions.

Comment: The question is the question. How to update database with array of objects. Above you can see my thinking. What i want to know is which is the best way to do that.

Comment: [Multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Comment: This is a perfect example of why not to use arrays in NoSQL databases. Their use is highly situational and there are usually much better ways to store and organize data. See this older post [Arrays are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815117/add-an-item-to-a-list-in-firebase-database/39817592#39817592). Calling update repeatedly in a tight loop is generally discouraged but the real issue is trying to do it with an array in Firebase. Create parent/child nodes to store that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no harm in calling the `update()` function repeatedly. All the requests to the database are going over a single connection, so the overhead per call is minimal.

But you might want to do a single update for atomicity: to ensure either all writes are allowed, or none of them are allowed.

Here's one way to do that, by looping over the changes in JavaScript:

```
var changes = [
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "y"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "z"
  },
];
var updates = {};
changes.forEach((change) => {
  updates[change.id] = change.value;
});
ref.update(updates);
```