# How do I save data in Firebase without overwriting current data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like allow a user to make numerous post without overriding the information that's stored under their UID I am aware of the push method that randomly generates a key but I would rather not use that. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated. In the method below I basically saved a dictionary containing the user's information into a [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) realtime database. But the information is being replaced due to the set value method.

Database:

```
Post
 NEbIdbCumcOnIbPdUQxpwtV7Dr63 (UID)
 desc: "Toue moe"
 id:   "NEbIdbCumcOnIbPdUQxpwtV7Dr63"
 image: "Contains some image"
 name:  "Some name"
 profileimage:  "Image"
```

Code:

```
public void saveToFirebase() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    //final String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").child(userId);
    storageRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        url = uri.toString();
                        postDictionary.put("desc", descriptionEditText.getText().toString());
                        postDictionary.put("image", url);
                        postDictionary.put("id", userId);
                        postDictionary.put("name",name);
                        postDictionary.put("profileimage", profileImage);
                        productsDatabaseRef.child("Post").child(userId).setValue(postDictionary);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Upload_Post.this, Shop_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    //handles error
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Upload_Post.this, "Error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hey arron, you can use firebase updateChildren() method for database reference

Comment: Hi I tried using that like this but the current information is still being replaced                            productsDatabaseRef.child("Post").child(userId).updateChildren(postDictionary);

Comment: show your firebase database node

Comment: I edited my question please check above. That's how it's structured. I'm basically trying to allow user's to make numerous post and save the information under their UID.

Comment: hmm i see that in your postDictionary map you included everything that you have in your database node. that's why all are replacing

Comment: in your postDictionary map only put those that are to be replaced. Then it will work

Comment: I am not trying to update the node, I am trying to allow the user to post something new without overriding what's already there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an item to a list in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815117/add-an-item-to-a-list-in-firebase-database)

Answer (score 0):

i was also having the same problem. but i solved it by adding timestamp/date.
just an idea!
here...

```
Post
 NEbIdbCumcOnIbPdUQxpwtV7Dr63 (UID):
         (CURRENT_TIME):
              desc: "Toue moe"
              id:   "NEbIdbCumcOnIbPdUQxpwtV7Dr63"
              image: "Contains some image"
              name:  "Some name"
              profileimage:  "Image"

         (CURRENT_TIME):
              desc: "Tou"
              id:   "NEbIdbCumcOnIbPdUQxpwtV7Dr234"
              image: "Contains some image"
              name:  "Some name"
              profileimage:  "Image"
```

i mean create a child as (current_time of updating the post) inside uid.
and then insert new post inside the current_time.

to implement that add this to your java file-

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

//defining date and time and storing it in currenttime variable.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
    String currenttime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

now make changes here as follows...

```
 final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").child(userId);
            storageRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
    String currenttime = sdf.format(new Date());


storageRef.child(currenttime).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() 



{
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                url = uri.toString();
                                postDictionary.put("desc", descriptionEditText.getText().toString());
                                postDictionary.put("image", url);
                                postDictionary.put("id", userId);
                                postDictionary.put("name",name);
                                postDictionary.put("profileimage", profileImage);
                                productsDatabaseRef.child("Post").child(userId).setValue(postDictionary);
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Upload_Post.this, Shop_Activity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
```

or instead of adding timestamp, you can add numbers to define each post by inserting it in for loop.
hope this helps!!

To retrieve the data from firebase-

```
final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").child(userId);

storageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String[] date=dataSnapshot.getKey().toString(); //here you will get the date/time //this is an array to store all date/time inside userid
                 //for example, 2019.08.5 at 10:05:33

                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2:dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                        //here u will get the values inside the date/time i.e desc,id,image,name,profileimage.
                        //code to retrieve the data will come here
                        }   
                }
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented the time stamp and my database looks as you describe, if I would like to access the post node with the newly added time stamps how would I do that?

Comment: i have added the info above to retrieve the data from firebase!! let me know the output after executing.In the above code, we are making a loop inside userId. first loop it will take 1st date then go inside the 2nd loop and retrieve the info..then again go in 1st loop and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow each user to upload multiple images, call `push()` to generate a new child node for each image:

```
productsDatabaseRef.child("Post").child(userId).push().setValue(postDictionary);
```

Calling `push()` generates a so-called `push ID`, which is guaranteed to be unique across all clients. To learn more about these IDs, see [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).