# Append item in array in Firebase Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of subscriber Ids and I want to append a new Id.
One way to do it is to read the array, append the item locally and then update the whole child. But I don't need to load it and I would like to append a new item directly in the array.

The only tutorial/example I found doing it in this way, is unfortunately using Firestore and notre Realtime database. He uses the code below :
`ref.document("blabla").update("node", FieldValue.arrayUnion("new item to append"));`
However, there is not an equivalent of
`update()` in Firebase api.

My document structure :
[image]

I know that is not recommended to use arrays in Firebase (I saw it somewhere) but for the moment I would love to find a way to do this without loading the entire list.

Comment: You can't - you must read the entire array in order to modify it and update it back to the same location.  There is no equivalent to the Firestore operation you cited here.  I suggest following the advice in this post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: If you're looking for `arrayUnion`, I highly recommend changing your data model and storing the values as keys. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815117/add-an-item-to-a-list-in-firebase-database/39818404#39818404